# API separate requests laravel

Tags: php, laravel, api, cron

Im trying to get multiple request of same function.
Im using this lib - https://github.com/uldisn/sharkscope

Important part for me is this:

```
$client = new SharcScopeClient($domain, $appName, $userName, $password, $appKey);
        
        if($client->requestPlayerStatistic('username')) {
            $playergames = $this->client->responseData;
        }
```

API can request only one player, and I need to make this function on repeat with different usernames.
I tried this:

```
$client = new SharcScopeClient($domain, $appName, $userName, $password, $appKey);
$users = User:all();      
foreach ($users as $user) {  
        if($client->requestPlayerstatistic($user->name)) {
            $playergames = $this->client->responseData;
        }
}
```

but still getting only one (first user) response data.

[dd($groupList) image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yxZY3.png)

I need to created functions for each users? Maybe is it possible to do something with cronjobs, or maybe you have better ideas? Thanks

Comment: How do you transform your data? it seems like something is missing from your question or not quite clear what you are actually asking, should playergames be array what is the problem?

Comment: $playergames = $playergames['Response']['PlayerStatistics']['Player]['games'];